# Generators of a field extension determine an automorphism

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

> Lemma: Suppose $K=F(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ldots,\alpha_n)$ is a field extension and $\sigma \in Aut(K)$ such that $\sigma$ fixes $F$ pointwise. Then $\sigma$ is uniquely determined by $\{\sigma(\alpha_i):1 \leq i \leq n\}$.

Proof:- Establishing uniqueness is straightforward. For any $\tau \in Aut(K)$ with the same properties, set $E=\{\alpha \in K: \sigma(\alpha)=\tau(\alpha)\}$. Then $E$ is a subfield of $K$ containing $F$ and all the $\alpha_i$, and hence $K$, thereby implying $K=E$, i.e., $\sigma = \tau$.

However how do we know the action of $\sigma$ on a general element of $K$?

Comment: An element $c$ of $K$ is a rational function of $\alpha_i$'s with coefficients in $F$. Since $\sigma$ fixes $F$ we conclude that $\sigma(c) $ is nothing but a rational function of $\sigma(\alpha_i) $'s with coefficients in $F$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh How do we know that any element of $K$ is in such form?

Comment: What's your definition of $F(\alpha_i) $? Does it mean smallest field containing $F$ and $\alpha _i$?

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Yes. However in a ring-theoretical context the notation $F(x)$ means the field of fractions of $F[x]$ to me.

Comment: Using the definition in my previous comment you should be able to conclude that elements of $K$ are rational functions of $\alpha_i $'s with coefficients in $F$.